# Bootstrap Css class in dynamic button on Ajax Call

Tags: c#, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to apply bootstrap button to dynamically create buttons via Ajax Call.In my code without bootstrap css class it's working on just default buttons But i want to apply bootstrap button When i use bootstrap css class --> class=btn btn-large btn-primary,Then it's not working

My Code

```
  function LoadSpecialFilesToUser() {
       debugger;
       var newurls = '<%= ResolveUrl("/WebMethods.aspx/GetSpecialFilesToUsers") %>';

        $.ajax({
            url: newurls,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: "<%=GetUserID()%>" }),
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (Result) {

               $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {

                   $("#SpecialFiles").append("<button class=btn btn-large btn-primary><a href=" + value.FilePath + "/>" + value.Caption + "</button>");//<-- In here without class=btn btn-large btn-primary.It's working 
               });

           },


           error: function (e, x) {
               alert(x.ResponseText);
           }
       });
   }
```

Comment: you're putting a link inside a button? try applying the classes to the link, and get rid of the button.

Comment: Have you tried putting the classes of the button between (escaped) double quotes?